# How to get contents of a child div javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql, ajax

I want to get the get the contents of a div that's inside another div and put them in a list, to send it to the database after that. 
I loop around the div and get all it's contents but all what it just returns the content of the first item of the loop.

The Div looks like this:

```
     $('#Classes').append('<div> <h1 class = "flip" wpID="' + subjects[i].Wkp_ID+ '</h1><div id ="NewBody" class="panel" contenteditable>' + subjects[i].Wkp_Body + '</div> </div>');
```

I use these lines to get the content:

```
     $('#Classes div').each(function (index) {
        var header = $(this).children('h1');
        var wpID = header.attr('wpID');
        var WeekBody = document.getElementById("NewBody");
        var Weekbodycontent = WeekBody.innerHTML;

   WeekPlan[index] = {"Wkp_Body": WeekBody};
   });
```

So , do you know how can I add all the items to the list one by one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues.  First off, you can't have the same ID present in more than one object in your document.  You need to change that.

Then, I would suggest this type of solution using a class on the desired `.panel` div:

```
$('#Classes').append('<div class="container"><div class="panel" contenteditable>' + 
    subjects[i].Wkp_Body + '</div> </div>');

$('#Classes .container').each(function (index) {
    var header = $(this).children('h1');
    var body = $(this).find(".panel");
    var Weekbodycontent = body.html();
    WeekPlan[index] = {"Wkp_Body": body.get(0)};
});
```

Comment: Ok this would be great, but there is a problem, before the second div I have a header that has some attributes which I use at my code too ... This is what it looks like:

Comment: $('#Classes').append('<div> <h1 class = "flip" wpID="' + subjects[i].Wkp_ID + '" lessonID="' + subjects[i].Ttb_lessonID + '" Date="' + Datecoming + '">' + subjects[i].sbj_Name + " Class:" + subjects[i].Ttb_Class + '</h1><div class="panel" contenteditable>' + subjects[i].Wkp_Body + '</div> </div>');

Comment: If you want precise help show us your actual HTML.  I can only go by the HTML you've disclosed.  And, please don't put multi-line code into comments (as it's unreadable).  If you need to add multi-line code, add it to your question using the `edit` link and then add a comment  directing people to the new part of your question.

Comment: @OnlyHope - OK, I've edited my answer to try to match the HTML I think you're using.

Comment: Which DOM element is supposed to go in the `WeekPlan[index]`?  Is it the `class="panel"` div?  Or the one that contains the `h1` tag?